# Rails, 2 namespaces, 1 resource. how to design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a resource blog.
I have a namespace admin that can create, see, delete blogs.
app/controllers/admin/blogs_controller.rb
Admin have its own portal

The route is pretty standard:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :blogs
end
```

and a standard user that have another portal and can just see the blogs and see the details of one blog.

I just implemented two methods in app/controllers/main_controller that look just like the index and show methods of Admin::BlogsController.
The route is:

```
get '/main/blog' => 'main#blog'
get '/main/blog/:id' => 'main#blog_show'
```

How can I improve my design?

Answer (score 0):

is this solution which are you looking for?

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :blogs
end
namespace :main do
   resources :blogs, only: [:show, :index]
end

app/controllers/admin/blogs_controller.rb

Admin::BlogsController


app/controllers/main/blogs_controller.rb

Main::BlogsController
```

Comment: the show and index method will be very similar in both blogs_controller.rb. But I think it is normal to have a lot of duplication in controller, isn't it?

Comment: Is good to separate admin controler action with main. It it will be the same, you can create service and call it in those two actions.